# Python: путь к SQL для импорта БД

Tags: python, база-данных

Я перед запуском программы (теста) удаляю БД (отработанную с прошлого запуска) а потом импортирую чистую БД. В данный момент я это реализовал через запуск Bash скрипта:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD -e 'drop database if exists NameDB'
cd ~/address_to_db
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD < NameDB.sql
```

а в коде пайтона вызываю через subprocess

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("./NameDB.sql", shell=True)
```

Мне кажется выполнение баш скрипта средствами пайтона не самый лучший вариант, по этому я хотел бы вынести путь к SQL файла в переменную, для этого у меня есть файл конфигурации.

Может есть более нормальный способ для реализации моей задачи?

Comment: Для  удаления БД я погуглил и реализовал это через модуль: ```from sqlalchemy import create_engine``` Далее подключаюсь к БД: ```DB = create_engine(
    f"mysql://{db_config.DB_LOGIN}:{db_config.DB_PASSWORD}@{db_config.DB_HOST}/{db_config.DB_NAME}?charset=utf8",pool_recycle = db_config.POOL_RECYCLE
)``` и удаляю её ```def dropLocalDB(): """Get sms auth token code"""
    query = """DROP DATABASE cloud;"""DB.execute(query).scalar()``` Сейчас буду искать альтернативу по импорт/экспорт, но в целом успехи есть, хотя може вы порекомендуете как-то по другом у это можно реализовать?